# route not mapping mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am  new in mvc and I have a situation where I am convinced that I am mapping a route correctly although it is not.

it is a very basic login form with the option of passing in parameters.

this is the html

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("LoginForm", "Home", new {userName="user"})">Login</a></li>
```

and this is the action method in the 'Home' controller

```
public ViewResult LoginForm(string userName)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

This is how is my attempt at mapping the route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Login/{userName}",
            new { controller = "Home ", action = "LoginForm", UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

The url is however displaying as follow

```
/Home/LoginForm?loginUser=user
```

my aim would be the following

```
Login/user
```

Advice perhaps as to why it is not mapping correctly. I have already registered a number of routes in the Global.asax.cs file. Could it have something to do with the order with which they were registered?

Comment: It appears that you are specifying "userName" in your MapRoute but you're passing an object called "loginUser".... You need to call them the same name.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation with code.

Comment: Hi. thanks. Did make the correction but still have the same problem.

Comment: What other routes do you have? It might be that this route gets overwritten. Btw, change `LoginForm` to `Login` in your action link.

Comment: try avoiding `null` in the `MapRoute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting a different address than the one specified in `MapRoute`. The mapped route will not fire. Change both the parameter and the action name.

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Home", new {userName="user"})">Login</a></li>
```

You need to access `/Home/Login` not `/Home/LoginForm`. The routing is done automatically **if** the right address is accessed.

**EDIT**:
Following your address edit:

- As far as I know, you cannot generate a link such as `Login/{userName}` using `Url.Action`; if you don't specify a controller, this defaults to `Home` controller
- You can however access the `Login/{userName}` link directly from the browser (due to the mapped route)
- You can create a "static" (i.e. classic) link, passing a hard-coded address:
  `<li><a href="/Login/user">Login</a></li>`

Please note that the `userName` added/removed per JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("LoginForm", "Home", new {userName="user"})">Login</a></li>
```

change the parameter **loginUser** to **userName**.

Comment: Hi. thanks. Did make the correction but still have the same problem. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Use ***userName*** instead of ***loginUser***

```
<li><a href='@Url.Action("LoginForm", "Home", new {userName="user"})'>Login</a></li>
```